# Issue appending info from networkx dict to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

Trying to take strings from my networkx dict and append them to a certain place within an array:

```
def sameSports(node1, node2, G):

    A = [G.node[node1]['sport1'], G.node[node1]['sport2'], G.node[node1]['sport3']]
    B = [G.node[node2]['sport1'], G.node[node2]['sport2'], G.node[node2]['sport3']]

    sharedSports = np.intersect1d(A,B)
    sharedSports = np.delete(sharedSports, np.where(sharedSports == 'N/A'))

    return sharedSports

def meetingDay(sharedSports,rightAxis):
    
meetingDays = [[] for i in range (len(sharedSports))]

    columns=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']
    for i in range (0,5):
        for t in sharedSports:
            n=np.where(sharedSports==t)
            meetingDays[n].append(t)
            if t in rightAxis[i]:
                meetingDays[n].append(columns[i])
    return meetingDays
```

The G.node[n]['sport'] dicts return single letter strings 'A'-'W', and the rightAxis array is a 5-section array containing some of the same letters. Getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\main.py", line 18, in 
a,b=add_sport_to_edges(G , rightAxis)
File "C:\Users\rjtkr\OneDrive\Documents\Work\Summer 2020 Research\epidemic\Athletics Network\sportsnetwork.py", line 99, in add_sport_to_edges
temp = meetingDay(sharedSports, rightAxis)
File "C:\Users\rjtkr\OneDrive\Documents\Work\Summer 2020 Research\epidemic\Athletics Network\sportsnetwork.py", line 90, in meetingDay
meetingDays[n].append(t)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Unsure if it's 'n' or 't' that it doesn't like, but fairly sure that neither is a tuple. Hopefully I included all relevant code. The other lines showing up in the error come after the attached code, and the error remains the same when they are removed.

Comment: Take a look at `n`. `np.where` returns a tuple.

Comment: `t` isn't being used as an index, so the problem has to be `n`  You can easily check what that is - the docs, a simple test expression, or a print.

Comment: Yep, fixed it up. Always assumed np.where returned a positional int. Thanks!